# Counting number of similar strings in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grouping, similarity

I have a table that contains a list of search_terms in Postgresql and the number of times they were searched:

[Search Term Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S9u7.png)

I'm trying to write a query that groups them together i.e. I want to see that electric scooter has been searched 27 times rather than 20 with 4 misspelt one way and 3 misspelt the other. I want to use the similarity function so that I can play with the limit.

I have been trying something along the lines of grouping by similarity but with no success:

```
SELECT 
search_term,
SUM(count)

FROM 
t2

GROUP BY (SELECT set_limit(0.8);

SELECT similarity(n1.search_term, n2.search_term) AS sim, n1.search_term, n2.search_term
FROM   t2 n1
JOIN   t2 n2 ON n1.search_term <> n2.search_term
               AND n1.search_term % n2.search_term
ORDER  BY sim DESC)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The value 0.8 is not enough. because similarity in your example is 0.6 and more

Try this query

```
SELECT sim, ss, sum(countt)
  FROM (
    SELECT sim, '|'||string_agg(s1,  '|')||'|' ss
      FROM (
        SELECT similarity(n1.search_term, n2.search_term) AS sim, 
               n1.search_term s1, n2.search_term s2
          FROM t1 n1
          JOIN t1 n2 ON n1.search_term <> n2.search_term
           AND n1.search_term % n2.search_term
           ) t2    
     WHERE sim > 0.6
     GROUP BY sim 
       ) t3
  LEFT JOIN t1 n3 ON ss like '%|'||n3.search_term||'|%' 
 GROUP BY ss, sim
 ORDER BY sim DESC
```

Here my sample - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1d705/35

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but that didn't really work as it you try to add more terms to your schema, they get lost. For example, try:  ('electric scooer',3),
('elecric scooter',4),
('electric scooter',20),
('road bicycle',5),
('camera',15),
('5D camera',12),
('segway longboard',15),
('boosted longboard',15);

Comment: @user10670868 you can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/33cc1/5 link. There is data. But maybe, similarity value is low